# jquery UI draggable and droppable clone option not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Hi all i am trying to enable drag and drop between two main containers(ids #container1 and container2) and a clone of the div items within them. I am using jquery UI and so far I am able to drag both items. However I am having the following problem

Although I have declared the clone helper for items in #container1, the drag behaviour still carries over the original div.

Any Ideas as to why this is?

Here is my coffee-script

```
jQuery ->
  $container1 = $("#container1")
  $container2 = $("#container2")

  $("div", $container2).draggable({helper: "clone"})

  $("div", $container1).draggable()


  $container1.droppable
    accept: "#container2 div",
    drop: (event,ui) -> 
       $( this ).append(ui.draggable)

  $container2.droppable
    accept: "#container1 div",
    drop: (event,ui) -> 
      $(this).append(ui.draggable)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, you define `$container2 = $("#container2")`

and then you include it inside `$( )` So you may try it like:

```
 $container1 = $("#container1")
 $container2 = $("#container2")

 $("div").draggable({helper: "clone"});
 $container2.draggable({helper: "clone"});  //----

 $("div").draggable();
 $container1.draggable();                 //----

 $container1.droppable
 accept: "#container2 div",
 drop: (event,ui) -> 
 $( this ).append(ui.draggable)
 $container2.droppable
 accept: "#container1 div",
 drop: (event,ui) -> 
 $(this).append(ui.draggable)
```

Then it should be work..

Comment: Thanks Ashish for your suggestion, unfortunately this has not resolved the issue. The original item is still been dragged across.

Comment: Is you able to put your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ so i will get it where error occurs?

Comment: Hi Ashish, sure here is my code on jsfiddle [code_sample](http://jsfiddle.net/4AF72/)